# Gamma color problem on Lion

Tags: macos

I have a MBP with Lion 10.7.2 with an external monitor. When I disconnect the MBP from the external Monitor or when I reconnect it, some application show incorrect gamma color.

It is very difficult for me to explain the aspect variation, but I can solve the problem going into the Monitor preferences -> Color profile and choose the profile of my monitor. This work for Finder and Mac app, but no for other application such as Chrome, that I have to close and restart.

I try to put an image with the incorrect color gamma:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try keep pressing command-option-control-comma

Comment: what is this command?

Comment: ok, I found it...but it doesn't change anything (but the gamma yes). So maybe It doesn't be a problem of Gamme...

Comment: Really?  Because that does sort of look like the contrast problem.  Try going to System Preferences - Universal Access - Seeing - Enhance contrast and check if the slide bar is at normal.  If it is and the problem is still there, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Nope...But changing the color profile (select another one and reselect the monitor's one) solves the problem. It's very strange...

Comment: +1 Thanks, this has fixed my problem! If you are even in London I'll buy you a beer. I've been going NUTS with this issue for weeks, maybe a few months now! Was starting to think my display was broken as I couldn't resolve it though changeling the display profile, I must have mashed command-option-control-period at some point!